# Get Android app without expansion files from Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

I wonder how Google Play decide if user will download full .APK file with expansion files (main, patch...) or just simple .APK file without expansion files.

I've read some articles about how to implement download service for missing expansion files inside our application, but there is a lack of information about how to test it.

What do you think about uploading application on Google Play with main expansion file, and then install signed .APK from our development machine (not Google Play).

Theoretically if we have download service in our app it should start and get missing main expansion file from Google Play?

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to put obb file on location

Device Memory > Android > obb > package name > obb file.

In your application you need to add code which if obb file is there not download.

So it will never download if obb file is not there.

Hope it will help you.

Let me know if you need more help from my side.

Comment: Yeap I know that - it's one case of testing .obb files without uploading app to Google Play. However I wonder how to test download service - so I want to have situation when I have .APK file and .obb file is missing - so app will run download service to get it.